# Azure: run database migrations after deploying from GIT

Tags: .net, azure, entity-framework-migrations

I'm trying to run database migrations after a GIT deployement on Azure. I don't know what is the correct way to do this, currently i'm follwing this [post](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsazure/en-US/655772ea-ea75-4492-8a9e-7f5d760b6f41/using-git-azure-ef-code-first-migrations-am-i-doing-it-wrong?forum=azuregit).

Here is my [deploy.cmd](https://github.com/gkatai/Timetable/blob/master/deploy.cmd)

I added this one line only:
`migrate.exe GitAzureCodeFirstSpike.dll /startUpDirectory="%DEPLOYMENT_TARGET%\bin" /startUpConfigurationFile="%DEPLOYMENT_TARGET%\Web.config"`

The deploymnet log says, that it can't find the migrate.exe command, but I don't know how to tell where it is.

What am I doing wrong? Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: You have to copy migrate.exe into your bin directory This page details on devs journey troubleshooting issues with migrate.exe which culminates in a bug that prevents this scenario from working anyway http://www.busydevelopers.com/article/42147908/Using+Git+%2B+Azure+%2B+EF+Code+First+Migrations+-+Am+I+doing+it+wrong%3F